# rendering JSON in django template without having to escape the entire JSON?

Tags: json, django, django-templates

In my django view I produce a JSON data that my template needs to use:

```
languages = { ... } 
context = {
   'languages': json.dumps(languages)
}
return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Then in the template, instead of just doing `var languages = {{languages}};` I need to do this because some strings might break the javascript:

```
var languages = JSON.parse('{{languages|safe|escapejs}}');
```

Which outputs a messy blob like this:

```
var languages = JSON.parse('[{\u0022name_english\u0022: \u0022Afar\u0022, \u0022code\u0022: \u0022aa\u0022, \u0022name\u0022: \u0022Afar\u0022}, {\u0022name_english\u0022: \u0022Afrikaans\u0022, \u0022code\u0022:...
```

I would really like to have this in my rendered template:

```
var languages = [{"name_english": "Afar", "code": "aa", "name": "Afar"}, {"name_english": "Afrikaans", "code": "af", "name": "Afrikaans"}, {"name_english": "Akan", ...
```

But as I said there is the need for escaping. Is there a way to just escape the strings that really need escaping and not the whole JSON? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the autoescape template tag.

```
{% autoescape off %}
    var languages = JSON.parse('{{languages}}');
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: This works for some/most JSONs but the problem with this is that some part of the json might need to be escaped. For instance if there is a string that contains some html such as `</script>`

Answer (score 0):

I found this template filter that escapes only what's necessary https://github.com/yourcelf/escapejson

it renders `{'test': '</script>'}` as `{"test": "<\/script>"}`